# Do Graph queries have a maximum response size?

Tags: events, data-feeds, graphs

I'm running a [Graph](https://thegraph.com/) node for a personal project and I'm wondering if there is a defined maximum response size for queries. I see that pagination is an option according to [the documentation](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/querying/graphql-api/#pagination), but it's not required.

Do thegraph.com nodes have a max response size? when do I need to use pagination?